# No module named 'kernmagic' in ipython

Tags: python

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 and upon starting up ipython (0.13.2), I get this warning:

```
ImportError: No module named kernmagic
```

I've tried re-installing ipython and that didn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of the warning?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14585313/1903116

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't work. Said there is no command called egginst. Tried looking this up but didn't really get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just completed a quick-and-dirty port of `kermagic` to python3. Are you using python3? If so, then [clone the code from Github](https://github.com/wesesque/kernmagic), and good luck!